# How to create a new contact in phone from website, when website opened in mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native, contacts

My question is: How can I create a new contact in the phone book of the user in mobile phone from my website when a Add to Contact button is clicked. If the user is using my website from a mobile browser?

If I can do this, then how? and I can't then, what is it's alternative?

Comment: There are native ways for mobile apps of course. For web, there is a scheme that works for iOS and MacOS [addressbook://](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AddressBook/Tasks/URLScheme.html), but I'm pretty sure it doesn't work for Android, don't have any devices on hand to test.

Comment: Do I need a macbook for this?

Comment: Shorty yes, an iPhone or macbook, but you could try if it works on android, but as far as I know it doesn't work.